# New Build PC - blue screens (BSOD) during OS (Win7) install attempts

Tags: memory, motherboard, bsod, computer-building

A recent PSU failure prompted a more wide spread upgrade of my desktop. This is a new build with a couple of older components.

**New build specs:**

Motherboard: Asus Z87-Pro

CPU: Intel i3-4130 (Haswell, but not refresh - has out of the box support from my MoBo)

PSU: XFX-XTR 750W (Gold)

RAM: Corsair 2x4gb 1833MHz DDR3 - quoted on the approved memory by the manufacturer.

SSD: new Sansung 840 EVO 250GB

Brought from my old build:

Graphics Card: ASUS EAH6850

Optical drives/case etc

**Symptoms:**

On first power up got POST message - new processor installed etc - moved to BIOS and set up system time etc. Everything seemed ok until a sudden BSOD with an irql_not_less_or_equal error message.   Google told me this was often memory related, so I switched my RAM to slots A2/B2 (which I note is the recommended configuration for 2 sticks).

At that stage I got to BIOS again, and this time the system seemed stable in BIOS - thinking I had found the problem I began an install of the OS, but got another BSOD this time quoting SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION.

The motherboard comes with a 'Memory OK' feature that auto checks the memory is compatible with the system (and presumably is in good health), I ran this and got a "Success" message in POST.

Howver, always getting BSOD during Windows install, I tried the following configurations:

- A1/B1
- A2/B2
- A2 only
- B2 only

No change, I always see a BSOD at the same point in the OS [Windows7] install (after windows has been "unpacked" I can select language, and agree to T&C, then format the intended drive, and then begin the install - the BSOD always ocurrs during "Extracting files (0%)..."

BSOD most commonly seen is STOP: 0x0000001E (with no named error)

Any advice greatly appreciated.

PS I have also optmized the voltage for the RAM via the on-stick XMP data (i.e. automatically via the BIOS feature that reads that)

EDIT: have tried SSD in both ACHI and IDE (and even RAID) / same result

RAM is explicitly tested as working by mobo manufacturer (exact ram model)

Comment: Corsair RAM and ASUS boards can be problematical. Make sure the RAM was tested wit this board.

Comment: I would also recommend that you set your hard disk interface to IDE (or "compatability") in your BIOS. It may be that the Win setup can't use your HDD until you've installed the drivers for AHCI. IDE mode gets around this by emulating an IDE controller. This can then be fixed when Windows has successfully installed and you can boot to it.

Comment: Thanks for the sufggestion bigchris, I tried SSD in both ACHI and IDE to no effect. Magicadre the ram is specified by manufacturer as compatible, memtest is clean, on board memok feature passes the memory as compatible.